# How do I make my WooCommerce Recent Products page to be in list view by default

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a website running on woocommerce. How do I make my WooCommerce Recent Products page to be in list view by default and not Grid view?

Comment: what research have you done on this before posting this question? Can you also add any applicable code to your question.

Comment: I have checked all around on other websites but cannot find what I want. I know there is a plugin for this but it's for the main Shop page. On my home page (http://finishlineretail.com/)  I have "Featured Products" and "Recent Products". I want "Featured Products" to be grid view and "Recent Products" to be list view like this website http://www.thinkretailsolutions.co.uk/store/

Comment: Style it differently.